# Mobilefirst 8.0 logs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Have two questions about MobileFirst Analytics Console and logs.

1. Here i have found some steps to log from java adapter https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/server-side-log-collection/java-adapter/
   I dont understand what the role play in MobileFirst Analytics Console and logs JavaLoggerTestResource class at this code:

   ```
   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JavaLoggerTestResource.class.getName());
   ```
2. I have found messages.log file at MobileFirst-8.0.0.0/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/logs/ folder. It contain all adapter exceptions. How can i see the file contents in the console?

Answer (score 0):

> I have found messages.log file at MobileFirst-8.0.0.0/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/logs/ folder. It contain all adapter exceptions. How can i see the file contents in the console?

I believe what you are looking for is actually "how to forward the logs related to your Java adapter to the Analytics server and have them displayed in the Analytics console.

See here for instructions: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/server-side-log-collection/java-adapter/#forwarding-logs-to-the-analytics-server

Essentially you need to go to your runtime settings view in the MobileFirst Console and setup log forward of your specific Java adapter (class name). The logs will then be displayed in the Analytics console's [Infrastructure view](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/console/#infrastructure).

> I dont understand what the role play in MobileFirst Analytics Console and logs JavaLoggerTestResource class at this code: `static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JavaLoggerTestResource.class.getName());`

That's how you set the logger. You create the logger and get the class name the logger relates to.

Comment: thx. in this way i can watch Logger stored messages. but i cant see jax-rs generated exception log, that stored in messages.log file. in messages.log file i watch all exception that was generated by jax-rs framework, catched, non catched(500). i need put out that info into analytic console.

Comment: in analytic console i can't see log written by adapter with system.out.println too.